# How to use pinch Gesture Recognizer in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ipad, xcode4.2, ios5

I have several items textfields, labels, and images on a UIScrollView. Is there a way to use the pinch Gesture to enlarge the screen to get a closer look of the items on the scrollview?

Comment: There are examples all over the web.  I recommend googling 'uiscrollview zoom'

Comment: Just need some help getting started

Comment: Again, I recommend google.  Or github.com for some example projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off try using the delegate function of the scroll view which is given below:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return yourView;
}
```

My assumption is that you have all the UI elements in one view and that view has to be returned in this function.

Comment: You should have had a view which contained all the text fields and rest and then add it as a subview to uiscrollview. In that case my answer would work.

Comment: Yes. It should do. Make sure the view contains everything you want to see zoomed.